# Django df to html show text

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

I am totally a new bee in Django, it's my 2nd day to learn it. I have already connected to the database and use the pandas.read_sql_query to get the df from database (I know there is ORM but since we use MSSQL, so it need more time for me to figure it out, and I really need to show sth at lease so I use pandas.read_sql_query)
I have already got the df and I want it to show in the html. According to some other posts, I use the code below:

view.py

```
a_query="""
select *
FROM db
"""
a = pandas.read_sql_query(a_query,connection)
a_html = a.to_html(index=False)
print(a)
print(type(a))
return render(request, 'index.html',{'a_html':a_html})
```

the type shows: So I think it's all good.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

index.html

```
I put {{a_html}} in the body part, it's the only thing I change after the original format.
```

after I run the manage.py, it shows this in html:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe"> <thead> <tr style="text-align: right;"> <th>IT Business Service</th> <th>IT Service Instance</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>
```

sth like that.

But I want to to show the table, how should I do for it? Any help is really apprecaited!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):

# Your SQL query
a_query = """
SELECT *
FROM db
"""
# Execute the query and fetch the data into a DataFrame
a = pd.read_sql_query(a_query, connection)

# Convert the DataFrame to an HTML table
a_html = a.to_html(index=False)

# Pass the HTML table to the template for rendering
return render(request, 'index.html', {'a_html': a_html})
```

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, thank you for answering the question : )this is what I do as well. But it show text

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Beginner here myself, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

If you have a container like a list, you can loop trough it and generate the table depending on the amount of entries:

```
<tr>
    <th>Table Headline</th>       
</tr>
{% for elem in my_data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{elem}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So format your data into an iterable and render it inside the html

```
return render(request, 'index.html',{'my_data':function_that_returns_data_as_a_list()})
```